# Calculating differential of function is a function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In mathematics most operation is function,such as addition 
,we can regards it as a function

$+$ : $R\times R$ $\to$ $R$

and Derivative

$\frac{d}{dx}$ : $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ $\to$ $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$

My question is whether or not calculating differential  of function is a function?

The differential represents the principal part of the change in a function.
for example $d(x^2)=2xdx$. My question is whether $d$ is a function?
If it is a function ,what is its codomain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory of integration tells you that the codomain of $d$ is the all space $\Omega^1(\mathbb R)$.